# Cascading merge updates with Flask-SQLAlchemy and MySQL 5.6

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am struggling with using `Flask-SQLAlchemy` for cascading merge updates in `InnoDB` powered `MySQL 5.6`.

I have two tables defined like so:

```
from sqlalchemy import BigInteger, Column, ForeignKey, String, Unicode
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

db = SQLAlchemy()


class Tweet(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tweet'

    tweet_id = Column(BigInteger(), primary_key=True)
    text = Column(Unicode(3000), nullable=False)
    urls = relationship("URL", backref="tweet", cascade="all,delete-orphan")


class URL(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'url'

    tweet_id = Column(BigInteger(), ForeignKey('tweet.tweet_id'), primary_key=True)
    short_url = Column(String(128), primary_key=True)
    long_url = Column(String(1024), nullable=False)
```

I want to "upsert" an existing tweet object `tweet_id=123`:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload

# I know this tweet exists already so I load it into current session
t = Tweet.query.options(joinedload("urls")).get(tweet_id=123)
# The `urls` are the same as what's already in the db
new_t = Tweet(tweet_id=123, text='hello world', urls=[URL(tweet_id=123, short_url='foo', long_url='bar')]
db.session.merge(new_t)
db.session.commit()
```

This throws:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry '123-foo' for key 'PRIMARY'") [SQL: u'INSERT INTO url (tweet_id, short_url, long_url) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'] [parameters: (u'123', 'foo', 'bar')]
```

I have been crawling SO for a while but have not found a hint as to why.